# remove <nobr> </nobr> string

Tags: jquery

I have the following variable which contains the following string. I would like to remove both the `<nobr>` and the `</nobr>` and just leave what is inside.

```
alert(product_code);
```

produces

```
<nobr>209/00254/01</nobr>
```

How would I make a new variable that removes the `<nobr>` tags?

```
var product_code = $(this).html();
alert(product_code);
```

Comment: @user, you can use the ` char to wrap inline code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to just remove them completely (from the original), you can use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) for example:

```
$("nobr").replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents() });
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Ja6ga/). Or, [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) result (since they'll be spaces in the result):

```
var product_code = $.trim($(this).text());
```

Comment: as always Nick you come thru with the specific, simple, answers that work exactly!!! product_code = $.trim($(this).text()); is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

```
var product_code = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 2):

try either:

```
$(this).text();
```

or

```
$(this).children("nobr").html();
```

Comment: I tried the first but that just gives me the text but with blank spaces after it. Will try second answer.

Comment: javscript error on the second response. XML filter is applied to non-XML value ({0:#1=({}), context:#1#, length:1})

Comment: You could always trim the string with the first answer.

Comment: Forget to add the call to the children method on the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

in case you have more than one:

$("nobr", this).each(function(){

$(this).replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents() });

});

Answer (score 0):

If the code is really just like that, you can do this with plain javascript:

```
product_code = '<nobr>209/00254/01</nobr>';

// using simple string manipulation
alert( product_code.substring( 6, product_code.length - 7 ) );

// using regular expressions
alert( product_code.match( '<nobr>(.*)</nobr>' )[1] );

// using a bit more powerful regular expression
result = product_code.match( '<nobr>((\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+))</nobr>' );
alert( result[1] ); // 209/00254/01
alert( result[2] ); // 209
alert( result[3] ); // 00254
alert( result[4] ); // 01
```